# Are there any instances you should use WCF over Web API?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I can see a few questions on here about WCF vs Web API, but they are relatively old (2012-early 2013), so I'm wondering if anything has changed with Web API 2.

Very simply, are there any instances one would chose WCF over Web API?

Are there any features on the Web API roadmap that will change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would only chose WCF if my project would need to support other protocols than HTTP REST.

Keep in mind that using WCF you may define multiple endpoints for the same service, supporting combinations like these (list is not supposed to be complete):

- REST over HTTP
- SOAP over HTTP (including WS-Security)
- Binary over TCP
- Binary over HTTP

In short. If you don't know exactly what protocol(s) your clients will be able to support, go WCF, otherwise REST using WebApi 2 would be the way to go.